# Sometimes my laptop boots into a weird looking screen

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia, 20.04

I have dual boot Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS and Windows 10. Sometimes my laptop boots into a weird looking screen and sticks there. Then I have to press and hold the power button to shut it down and boot it again. After some tries it turns on. How can I solve this issue?

> 

- Laptop: Asus vivobook D509DJ
- Processor: Ryzen 5 3500u
- GPU: Nvidia MX230

image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rERNr.jpg